# replace string in json

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to javascript and have this code which will replace the string from A to B, but if there is multiple records of As, it will only replace the first A, while the remaining will be remain as A. Note that the stringify is called twice.

```
"success": function(json) {
    var old = JSON.stringify(json).replace('"新交易"', '"待审核"');
    var newdata = JSON.parse(old);

    var old = JSON.stringify(newdata).replace('"批准"', '"已充值"');
    var newdata = JSON.parse(old);
    fnCallback(newdata);
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: Why you are using replace? You can change the property of the object

Comment: What is your `json`?

Comment: @isvforall It is solved. thanks anyway.

Comment: Side node: you've chosen slightly confusing variable names because `json` is not JSON (it's an object) and then you convert it to `old` (which *is* JSON).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has little to do with JSON. As [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> To perform a global search and replace, include the g switch in the regular expression.

So change this:

```
replace('"新交易"', '"待审核"')
```

... into this:

```
replace(/"新交易"/g, '"待审核"')
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace every word in your context use Regular Expressions. So check this example to see how it works:

```
    var someText = '"新交易""新交易""新交易""新交易""新交易""新交易""新交易""新交易"';
    var someText2 = '"批准""批准""批准""批准""批准""批准""批准""批准""批准""批准"';
    var old = someText.replace(/"新交易"/g, '"replaced"');
    var stuff = someText2.replace(/"批准"/g, '"已充值"');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n1otvpy1/